# getting the `current_user` in my User class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Oddly enough, most of this works as it has been written, however I'm not sure how I can evaluate if the `current_user` has a badge, (all the relationships are proper, I am only having trouble with my methods in my class (which should partially be moved into a lib or something), regardless, the issue is specifically 1) checking if the current user has a record, and 2) if not create the corresponding new record.

If there is an easier or better way to do this, please share. The following is what I have:

```
# Recipe Controller
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  def create
  # do something
  if @recipe.save
    current_user.check_if_badges_earned(current_user)
  end
end
```

So as for this, it definitely seems messy, I'd like for it to be just `check_if_badges_earned` and not have to pass the `current_user` into the method, but may need to because it might not always be the current user initiating this method.

```
# User model
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def check_if_badges_earned(user)
    if user.recipes.count > 10
      award_badge(1, user)
    end
    if user.recipes.count > 20
      award_badge(2, user)
    end
  end

  def award_badge(badge_id, user)
    #see if user already has this badge, if not, give it to them!
    unless user.badgings.any? { |b| b[:badge_id] == badge_id}
      @badging = Badging.new(:badge_id => badge_id, :user_id => user)
      @badging.save
    end
  end

end
```

So while the first method (`check_if_badges_earned`) seems to excucte fine and only give run `award_badge()` when the conditions are met, the issue happens in the `award_badge()` method itself the expression `unless user.badgings.any? { |b| b[:badge_id] == badge_id}` always evaluates as true, so the user is given the badge even if it already had the same one (by badge_id), secondly the issue is that it always saves the `user_id` as 1.

Any ideas on how to go about debugging this would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether you need the `current_user` behavior above, `award_badge` should just be a regular instance method acting on `self` instead of acting on the passed `user` argument (same goes for `check_if_badges_earned`).  In your `award_badge` method, **try `find_or_create_by_...` instead of the logic you currently have**.  For example, try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def award_badge(badge_id)
    badgings.find_or_create_by_badge_id(badge_id)
  end
end
```

---

To access the `current_user` in your model classes, I sometimes like to **use thread-local variables**.  It certainly blurs the separation of MVC, but sometimes this kind of coupling is just necessary in an application.

In your ApplicationController, store the `current_user` in a thread-local variable:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_thread_locals

  private

  # Store thread-local variables so models can access them (Hackish, but useful)
  def set_thread_locals
    Thread.current[:current_user] = current_user
  end
end
```

Add a new class method to your ActiveRecord model to return the `current_user` (you could also extend ActiveRecord::Base to make this available to all models):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current_user
    Thread.current[:current_user]
  end
end
```

Then, you'll be able to access the current user in the instance methods of your `User` model with `self.class.current_user`.

Comment: this is an excellent tip, I can see where I can use this elsewhere in my app, It is actually not super hackish (well maybe, but if you compare it with my work-arounds it is much closer to the MVC conventions I want) thanks Ryan!

Comment: and btw... I'm a huge fan of LMGTFY, just realized that you created it. awesome.

Comment: Aw, shucks, thanks, but gotta give props to my partner in crime, Jim Garvin (http://www.thegarvin.com/).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do first of all is make those methods class methods (call on self), which avoids needlessly passing the user reference.

Then, in your `award_badge` method, you should add the Badging to the user's list of Badgings, e.g.: `user.badgings << Badging.new(:badge_id => badge_id)`

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense.  Class methods would not avoid a user reference.  Also, his original code only added a badge if the user didn't already have that badge.  Your `award_badge` snippet would yield duplicate badges, and that's not what he was after.

Comment: @Ryan: you're right about the class method part. Don't know why I thought that. In fact what I meant was that since he has a reference to the current user, he doesn't need to pass that reference, he can just call the instance method directly. For the second part, I was just showing how to associate it with the user, it was indeed a snippet. Nowhere did I specify to drop his `if` statement.